# TypeScript: How to filter data that is in a separate component to the filter function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am currently working on a filter function for a table. 
I have one component for the table header and another for the table body. I am calling a function on the table header component to filter the data that is in the table body component.

The user input is being stored in the Table Header Component and onSearch calls the onFilter to work. 
Now that my data is in another component how do I call it so that it gets filtered and re-rendered and what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you say more about where you're stuck?  In general, you want to share state across different components, and then issue actions that update the state (e.g. a filter records action).  When the state changes, the components are re-rendered.  I'd recommend looking into [redux](https://redux.js.org/), which is a very common state container for react.  They have plenty of examples of how it all works together.

Comment: What I am currently struggling with is how to get the TableHeader component to get and filter the data that is in the TableBody component and then to pass the filtered data back to the TableBody component. The end result should be that the user types into the search bar and the data below sorts according to the input.

Comment: In React, we don't think in terms of passing data around, rather we think about sharing state between components.  If your working on a sample or small project, you can read [this article](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) which talks about _lifting state up_ so that it can be shared across components.  If it's a larger, more complex application, I'd recommend reading up on redux (link in previous comment) or [context](https://medium.com/@manishkumarr/using-react-context-api-to-share-state-between-component-89cad9a782cd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to handle this type of cross-component communication in React is through state management.  And one of the simplest ways to do this is by [*lifting state*](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a parent component. The parent component holds the state, and shares it with it's children as necessary.  When the state changes, the component is re-rendered, and the new state is passed to the child components, who then re-render as well.

A simple example of a parent component could look like this.

```
function ParentComponent(){
  [records, setRecords] = useState(profiles);

  const filterRecords = (filterString) => {
    const filtered = _.filter(records, r => r.name.indexOf(filterString) >= 0);
    setRecords(filtered);  //This will trigger a re-render
  }

  return (
    <table>
      <TableHeader onFilter={filterRecords} />
      <TableBody records={records} />
    </table>
  );
}
```

The `TableHeader` might look vaguely like this:

```
function TableHeader({onFilter}){
  return (
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button onClick={() => onFilter("billy")}>Filter Me</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  );
}
```

And the `TableBody` components might look vaguely like this:

```
function TableBody({records}){
  return (
    <tbody>
        {_.map(records, record => <tr><td>{record.name}</td></tr>)}          
    </tbody>
  );
}
```

With this structure (if I got all the pseudo-code dots connected), clicking the *filter me* button in the header will tell the parent component to filter the records, and update it's state, which will trigger a re-render, causing the body to update as well.